# Dynamically append element in JSF

Tags: jsf, dom, dynamic, append

I am using latest JSF and PrimeFaces. I would like to append additional row to my panelGrid when user clicks a link...

I am used to doing it with jQuery .click() and .append(). How can I achieve this with JSF/PrimeFaces?

Comment: Related: [Dynamically adding a row to primefaces dataTable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561982/dynamically-adding-a-row-to-primefaces-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a datatable instead of a panelgrid. A datatable allows you to display a dynamically sized collection of items in tabular format.

E.g.

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    ...
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}" update="table" />
```

with

```
private List<Item> items;

public void add() {
    items.add(new Item());
}

// ...
```