# Primefaces datatable scrolling not working as hoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have followed the primefaces showcase example for the datatable to make is scrollable across and while it works across it makes all the columns very small and i am unable to really read the columns, the reason for the scrollable function is because of the large amount of columns i need to display, is there any way of keeping the size of the columns but also make the datatable scrollable ?

here is the datatable code :

```
<p:dataTable id="UserTable"
   widgetVar="usersTable" 
   paginator="true" rows="10"
   value="#{usertableController.items}"
   var="item"
   emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria"
   scrollable="true" scrollWidth="400">
```

there are 14 columns in total i need to display

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always give `width= "X"` to your `<p:column>` or `<p:columns>`. It works when the datatable is scrollable. As follows,

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="15" />

<p:columns width="150" value="..." var="..." columnIndexVar="..." sortBy="..." filterBy="..." >
```

Comment: Hi there thanks but when i try to implement that i get `javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.`

Comment: Do you want to use selection? If not, do not use "selectionMode". If you do, did you try adding a "rowKey" to your datatable? You may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333764/datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamodel-when-selection