# primefaces datatable, set to list

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm using a data table like this

```
<p:dataTable id="runwaysTable" var="runway"
        value="#{of:setToList(airportHandler.theAirport.runways)}"
        selection="#{airportHandler.selectedRunway}" selectionMode="single"
        rowKey="#{runway.id}">
```

`runways` is a Set (result of Hibernate mapping).
So i'm using OmniFaces library to convert it to a list in order to work inside the datatable.

I added a rowKey to the datatable, 
but I'm still having `javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.`
I thought that using a rowKey was a good way not to implement SelectableDataModel (which I don't really want to do)

Comment: Look similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513873/datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamodel-when-selection

Comment: Your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253340/is-it-possible-to-create-editable-datatable-using-omnifaces-ofsettolist

Comment: thanks, I did not find it

Comment: You see BalusC's comment in answer !

Comment: Yes, my comment was meaning "I was not able to find it before asking the question my self". Thanks for sharing the link