# Is SelectableDataModel mandatory on <p:dataTable selection>; how do I implement it

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it mandatory create a class that implements `SelectableDataModel` when I want to use `selection` property on my `<p:dataTable>`? If yes, how can I "link" my dataTable with a class that implements `SelectableDataModel`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513873/datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamodel-when-selection/10514441#10514441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not necessary. You can just specify the `rowKey` attribute so that `<p:dataTable>` can figure the unique identifier of the row without the need for `SelectableDataModel`.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item" rowKey="#{item.id}" ...>
```

---

For the case you're interested, or need to, here's how you should implement it:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> items;
    private ItemDataModel itemModel;

    public Bean() {
        items = itemService.list();
        itemModel = new ItemDataModel(items);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Where the `ItemDataModel` look like this:

```
public class ItemDataModel extends ListDataModel<Item> implements SelectableDataModel<Item> {  

    public ItemDataModel() {
        // Default c'tor, keep alive.
    }

    public ItemDataModel(List<Item> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Item getRowData(String rowKey) {
        List<Item> items = (List<Item>) getWrappedData();

        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.getId().equals(rowKey)) {
                return item;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Item item) {
        return item.getId();
    }

}
```

Finally use `itemModel` instead of `items` as `<p:dataTable value>`.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.itemModel}" var="item" ... />
```